# Proving uniqueness of limits

Tags: limits, inequality

IF:
given $r$ there exist $k,m$ such that:
for all $a>0$ there exist $b>0,c>0$ such that:

$$\begin{align*}0<|x-r|<b&\implies|A(x)-k\,\,|<a\\
0<|x-r|<c&\implies|A(x)-m|<a\end{align*}$$

Then prove that $k=m$.
Where $A(x)$ is an algebraic quantity in $x$.

I do not know how to start with this inequality

Answer (score 0):

We will prove by contradiction.  Suppose that $k \not= m$; then let $d = |k-m|$.

However, suppose we then let $a = d/2$.  Then from the problem's premise, we can find some number $e$ (intuitively the minimum of $b$ and $c$) such that for all $x$ where $0 < |x-r| < e$, both

$$
|A(x)-k| < a = d/2
$$
$$
|A(x)-m| < a = d/2
$$

But now we have a contradiction.  By the triangle inequality,

$$
|A(x)-k|+|A(x)-m| \geq |k-m| = d
$$

But we already have that $d = 2a > |A(x)-k|+|A(x)-m|$.  Since it is impossible that $d > d$ (note *strictly greater than*), our original supposition must have been false, and $k = m$.

This is a demonstration of the uniqueness of a limit (under the stated conditions).  It might more familiarly be written as follows: Suppose that for a given $c$, there exist $L_1, L_2$, such that for any $\varepsilon$, there exist $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that

$$
0 < |x-c| < \delta_1 \to |A(x)-L_1| < \varepsilon
$$
$$
0 < |x-c| < \delta_2 \to |A(x)-L_2| < \varepsilon
$$

Then $L_1 = L_2$.

Comment: The proposition concerning  the uniqueness of a limit is the following:

Comment: Is what?  Was there a link that went missing?

Comment: The proposition for the uniqueness of a limit is the following:Given that $r$ is an accumulation pt in the domain A ,a subset in the real Nos,of the real function f,then if limf(x)=k and limf(x)=m as x goes to r ,then k=m.The definition of a limit is conditional.You do not have a limit if $r$ is not an accum pt point.You still think that the above problem represents the uniqueness of a limit?So ,you have produced a proof similar to the one for the uniqueness of a limit without taking into account that $r$ is an accum pt, because  the hypothesis of the problem does not demand so

Comment: Yes.  That is why I wrote "under the stated conditions".

Comment: "Under the stated conditions" i am sure if there is a proof.When i came accross this problem i detected ,the missing condition ( tthat of $r$ being an accum pt),hence i did not followed the proof of the uniqueness of limit.Coming now  to your proof ,youmade an assumption ,apart from others ,(0<|x-r|<e) that you did not close ,hence you violated the rule of conditional proof proof

Comment: As I said, $e$ is in an intuitive sense the minimum of $b$ and $c$.  I could've spelled it out and said, "Stipulate that $r$ is a limit point.  Find $b, c$ such that $|x - r| < b$ implies $|A(x)-k| < d/2$ and $|x - r| < c$ implies $|A(x)-m| < d/2$.  Let $e = \min\{b, c\}$."  Is that really necessary?  The answer is not meant to be a formal proof; it is meant to guide the OP to the sense of the demonstration, so they can make it as rigorous as they need to.  You've taken a comment that indicates the general gist of the proposition and blown it way out of proportion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23596/discussion-between-user149368-and-brian-tung).

Comment: Let's not. We obviously disagree and I see no point in continuing this. Let's just drop it.